# During the positive cycle of US AC MAINS Electricity is the secondary Voltage back EMF or in phase with the AC MAINS?

Tags: transformer, ac, mains, inductance, phase

The Sine wave of AC Mains in the US starts at zero and increases to Vmax~169-Volts. in the beginning magnetic Flux Change is greatest as it is proportional to the slope of the AC Sine wave (which is largest when crossing zero).

Does this mean that the Secondary has an EMF flowing the opposite direction as the Primary Windings AC Mains Current Flow and since EMF is largest when the rate of change in magnetic flux is largest then at the instant of zero crossing (from negative to positive voltage on the primary) would the secondary be equal to its maximum negative voltage excursion (or 270 degrees out of phase)?

Comment: What makes you think the power is a sine wave? It looks like a cosine to me... In other words, what do you mean by "in the beginning"?

Comment: Are you just pulling my leg? Cosine is a Sine wave phase shifted by -90 degrees. Assuming you turn on the switch such that the AC Mains is Crossing zero from negative VAC to Positive VAC at that exact moment. making it a Sine Wave where sin(t) at T=0 is the Voltage and is Zero when the AC MAINS is turned on (in my hypothetical circuit).

Comment: the point being made is you do not know when it starts so your opening statement of "The Sine wave of AC Mains in the US starts at zero and increases" is a false dictum. Starts when? when the generator kicks in? when a scope is connected.  So to re-affirm @ElliotAlderson point... What do you mean by "in the beginning"

Comment: Pardon me, as I wrote the question I guess I didn't think I had to indicate that information. I wasn't making some sort of statement about AC MAINS in general, I meant, "Imagine an AC Mains voltage that is a sine wave starting at zero." I figured people would understand that I wasn't postulating that AC Mains has a starting point and that the point was zero.

Comment: My question is, is the secondary waveform in phase with the primary waveform as the primary is inducing the magnetic field that is inducing the secondary and the primary would feel an impedance whereas the secondary is feeling a conductance.

Comment: You start talking about the "magnetic flux" and the "secondary" without ever mentioning that you have a transformer connected to the mains. We can sort of work it out, but it makes it much harder to follow your question. Can you explain in detail exactly what circuit you want to ask about? What kind of transformer are you using? What is the load on the secondary? etc.

Comment: This was just a thought I had and there is no circuit that bears any importance related to this question. You're right, I forgot to mention I was talking about the primary and secondary in a Transformer. I guess in my mind I was thinking where else does AC Mains go besides a transformer and mistakenly omitted the component. Andy Aka gave me the answer I was looking for. I wasn't considering the Primary current is shifted +90 degrees so the secondary Voltage induced by the B-field is shifted back -90 degrees so both the Primary and Secondary Voltages remain in phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is the secondary waveform in phase with the primary
>   waveform

If you are talking about voltages then yes, it is in phase (unless you reverse the secondary winding polarity). So it goes like this: -

- Primary voltage we can say has a phase reference of 0 degrees.
- Due to the inductor law (\$V = L\frac{di}{dt}\$), primary magnetization current is 90 degrees lagging.
- The magnetic flux in the core is in-phase with the magnetization current.
- Secondary induced emf is a further 270 degrees lagging because \$V = -N\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ (Faraday/Lenz law).

So, depending on the polarity of the secondary winding, the output may be in phase or inverted (180 degrees).

> in the beginning magnetic **Flux Change** is greatest as it is
>   proportional to the slope of the AC Sine wave (which is largest when
>   crossing zero)

If you mean as the sine wave voltage passes through zero then no, the **flux change** is zero: -

[image]

[Picture from here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-3/ac-inductor-circuits/).

As you can see the current slope is zero when voltage is passing through zero hence the **flux change** is zero. Flux and current are both at a maximum peak value but their rate of change is zero.

Comment: ahhhhhhh i SEE. I did not think about how the current would have shifted. Thank you very kindly!